# Get the type of my current class in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, types, instance

```vb
Public Sub New()
    If GridElement.typeList(getId(), getLayer()) Is Nothing Then
        GridElement.typeList(getid(),getlayer()) = GetType(me)
    End If
End Sub
```

Take a look at the snippet above.  On the third line, I'm trying to set a multidimensional array to the type that the current class is.  How can I get the type of the class that I am currently in?

I'm using VB.net so all .net examples are acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call [`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) (i.e. effectively `me.GetType()`) - you're already *in* an instance.

Comment: I had actually just figure this out!  Thanks for the help though Jon Skeet!  I'll set you as the answer in 9 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `GetType()` returned a "Type Expected" error.

I ended up using `[GetType]()` instead.

Since I wanted to return the type name in an error message, the complete result was something like this:

```
Throw New Exception($"Error in the {[GetType]().ToString} Class.")
```